# Googlebot increased the number of requests for a certain URL even though it has no links

Tags: seo, googlebot, web-crawlers, technical-seo, crawl-rate

As part of regular Log File Analysis, I noticed in a URL that `Google_bot` was crawling like crazy. This URL is an Iframe that embed in a page. My thought was maybe this page gets a new link from somewhere, but when I checked with SF/ahrefs none of those pages (Iframe URL & main page URL) get any link.

This page gets more requests than the home page in a one day, and it's consistent. Any Idea what happened here?

And let's say I crawl the whole site and dive really deep and I find 3 links for those pages for ex.
Still, why in one day `Google_bot` decides to increase the number of requests to this url like this? (hundreds of thousands)

P.S -

- The Inspection tool indicates this url is not in the index `(<meta name="robots" content="noindex">)`
- Referral page is only the main page that the iframe is embed into it
- According to Ahrefs, there's no backlink at all